# Difference in AIC between AR(p) and AR(p+1) models

Tags: arima, aic, likelihood

I have a situation where my *AR(2)* model has a lower AIC value *(-98.49)* than both the *AR(1)* *(-75.84)* and the *AR(3)* model *(-92.91)*. As you can see, the difference in AIC between the *AR(2)* and the *AR(3)* is *5.58*.

However, as I understand it, from the definition of the AIC, **-2*LogLik+2*npar**, it follows that the absolute difference in AIC between an *AR(p)* and *AR(p+1)* model can never be *>2*, since this would imply that the log-likelihood would have decreased after adding a parameter.

I have checked to confirm; the log-likelihood as computed by the *TSA* package (`my_AR_model$loglik`)
is in fact higher for the *AR(2)*, (*52.25*), than for the *AR(3)*, (*50.45*).

I have also confirmed that R isn't calculating the AICc, since this would only add 1.2 to the AIC (I have 24 observations).

So my question is: am I missing something? Can the log-likelihood actually decrease when adding a parameter, is there something special about how the *TSA* package calculates AIC, am I doing something wrong in R, or is R pulling my leg somehow?

**EDIT**:
The code and data I have been using are the following:

Data:

```
my_vector <- c(-0.15117448, -0.14348934, -0.18137095, -0.19605340, -0.20543727, -0.21709754, -0.21490577, -0.20853185, -0.19525812, -0.14138660, -0.12247660, -0.07981194, -0.01453317,  0.05647378,  0.11952508, 0.20328388,  0.26107555,  0.30314216,  0.29448029,  0.28686523,  0.22518196,  0.14278947,  0.07233569,  0.06609976)
```

Code:

```
my_timeseries <- ts(my_vector, frequency = 1)

ar2 <- arima(my_timeseries, order = c(2, 0, 0), method = "ML")

ar3 <- arima(my_timeseries, order = c(3, 0, 0), method = "ML")

ar2$loglik

ar3$loglik
```

Comment: can we have a reproducible example please?  Can you try with `stats::arima` and see if you get the same answers as with `TSA::arima` ?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I tried with stats now and it seems to work!

Comment: If you find a reproducible problem, could you please contact the maintainer of the TSA package (`maintainer("TSA")`) ?

Answer (score 3):

> Can the log-likelihood actually decrease when adding a parameter, is
>   there something special about how the TSA package calculates AIC, am I
>   doing something wrong in R, or is R pulling my leg somehow?

Yes, it can decrease when adding a parameter. Adding parameters usually increases the log-likelihood, and may substantially increase it, so much so that the decrease in negative twice this might outweigh the increase in the penalty term, which results in a decreased AIC.

It does appear difficult to get the AIC statistic to decrease by more than $2$ adding a parameter, however. Using some algebra, you can see that 
$$
-2\ell_1 + 2p - (-2 \ell_2 + 2[p+1]) > 2
$$
if and only if
$$
-2(\ell_1-\ell_2) + 2(p - (p+1)) > 2
$$
if and only if
$$
\ell_2 - \ell_1 > 2
$$
where $\ell_i$ is the log-likelihood for model $i=1,2$, and $p$ is the number of parameters for the smaller model. You can see it's unlikely, though, because this happens if and only if the likelihood ratio is bigger than $e^2$. I can't see why it can't happen at the moment, but I've tried a few examples and it seems to not like to go past it.

```
fakeData <- arima.sim(n = 200, list(ar = c(1.8, -.9), sd = sqrt(0.01))); plot.ts(fakeData)
AIC(arima(fakeData,order=c(3,0,0))); AIC(arima(fakeData,order=c(2,0,0))); AIC(arima(fakeData,order=c(1,0,0))); 
# [1] 606.0292
# [1] 604.5039
# [1] 922.0545
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However, my problem is not that the AIC statistic decreases after adding a parameter, but that it increases by more than two. The AR(2) has an AIC of -98.49. When adding one parameter, so that I have an AR(3) model, the AIC increases to -92.91. This is an increase of 5.58. Which means that the AR(3), i.e. model with three parameters, has a LOWER log-likelihood than the AR(2), i.e. model with only two parameters.

Comment: @J.Frank I could say more, perhaps, if you provided more information about your data/model/code.

Comment: I have added the data and code in an edit!

Answer (score 1):

The AIC is like a decoration on a christmas/holiday tree and you should also know that there is no Santa Claus. Additionally model parameters are simultaneously optimized thus they change based upon the model AND the # of linear equations used .I would put less belief on the AIC 
 (unless you have the same # of fitting points) and refer model selection to tests of necessity and sufficiency and ITERATE in a cautious way to that better model.

Comment: What does this mean

Comment: It explains that an AIC premises a particular # of estimating equations. If the y differ then the AIC's are not necessarily comparable.

Comment: Could you expand on "refer model selection to tests of necessity and sufficiency and ITERATE in a cautious way to that better model"? If necessarily I'll make a new question.

Comment: please make a new question and if you wish submit a data set of your choosing and I will try and be explicit ....